# Searching on Table using MySQL LIKE Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on crud functionality in php and mysql for user table.I have keep user status "a" and "d" for "active" and "deactive" respectivaly in database .My problem is when user search on frontend lets say "active" then how I can query to fetch all active status record.

Please help..

Comment: I know above query but i want when user enter active in search form then it search all the column name,email, phone,status

Comment: I wonder what problema are you facing. Could you edit your question and add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is: you keep either `a` or `d` in your table and user, on frontend, can enter whether `active` or `deactive`. So what you have, is `active` or `deactive` and based on that you need to pick records. Then you could use such query:

```
select * from statusesTable
where instr('active', statusColumn) = 1
```

Above query will return all records where `statusColumn` is `a`.